# If there is an equation $x^n=1$ then, we know the solution are of the form $\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$ , where $\alpha=\cos2\pi/n+\sin2$

Tags: group-theory

I was reading about group theory. There was a problem which states then: If there is an equation $x^n=1$ then, we know the solution are of the form $\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$ , where $\alpha=\cos2\pi/n+\sin2\pi/n)^k$(where $k={0,1,2,3,\ldots,n-1}$). If we consider a set $ G=\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ and the binary operation as $\cdot$ (where $\cdot$ denotes the usual multiplication ). Is $(G,\cdots)$ a group?

My solution goes like this:

> First , we verify Closure property . It states that if $\alpha,\beta\in G$ then $\alpha.\beta \in G$ . Here, if $\alpha^m,\alpha^n\in G$  then $\alpha^{m+n}\in G$ , which is true since $\alpha^{m+n}=\alpha^{nq+r}=\alpha^r\in G$ .Next, we prove associativity,  which is easily verified as $\alpha^{m+n+r}=\alpha^{m+n+r}$. Now, we need to prove $\exists e \in G $ such that $\forall  a \in G $ we have $e.a=a.e=a$ . Here $e=1$. Now, we need to prove the inverse property, which states that for every $a\in G$ there is a $a^{-1}\in G $   such that $a.a^{-1}=a^{-1}.a=e$ . But here arises the problem , if we consider $\alpha^m$ then its inverse is $\alpha^{-m}$ but $\alpha^{-m}\notin G$. So, inverse property is not satisfied for all elements in $G$. So, this cannot be a group.

However, the book says it is a group. How is  this possible? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: Assuming $0\leq m <n$, isn't $\alpha^{n-m} \in G$? and isn't $\alpha^m\alpha^{n-m} = 1$?

Comment: Also, I suppose you mean $\alpha = \cos 2\pi/n + i\sin 2\pi/n$ (you left out the imaginary unit $i$)

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** This is where your mistake lies. Suppose you are told
$$S = \{ f(1), f(2), f(3)\}$$
and you are asked whether $f(4)\in S$. You are thinking "No, because $4$ isn't one of $1$, $2$, or $3$."

The mistake is that it is possible to have, say, $f(4) = f(1)$, so that $f(4)$ **is** in $S$ (because it equals $f(1)$, which is in $S$).

So in your case, note that $\alpha^{-m}$ can be written many ways:

$$\cdots =\alpha^{-2n-m} = \alpha^{-n-m} = \alpha^{-m} = \alpha^{n-m} = \alpha^{2n-m} = \cdots$$ and one of these will be in $G$ since the exponents are spaced apart by $n$ and $G$ contains $n$ consecutive powers of $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it now...Thank you!...